# PHP - Database Table and Pages

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if I am saying this right or not but will try to explain it the best I can.

I have created a Database Table for my website - it stores information about Voice communications servers (TeamSpeak 3, Ventrilo, Mumble) - I want to create a page that will display them, easy enough.

I am creating a viewer (to see who is on the servers) and want to use 1 php page, so if a user click on the 4th TeamSpeak 3 server listed they will be taken to a url like this: http://yoursite.com/viewers/ts3/ts3.php?id=4 or something like that - so it just shows the 4th server. Right now I have a simple page that list all the servers in the database.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the item list, you may add a "details" icon, or the item's name itself should be a *link*, which points to `ts3.php?id=x` where *x* is the ID of the appropiate item. You're done.

Comment: As I understand you need to know how to handle `ts3.php?id=x` requests ?